# TFS Release pipeline: sequence the tests in specific order

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, mstest, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a use case to run test project to run test cases in **specific sequence** with in TFS release pipeline.
I see that Ordered test and Playlist are not an option any more what would be the process for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you will be able to do it in a scheduled manner.  The only way I think the ordering in a test plan is honored is when you execute it from the test plan directly.  There is some specific configuration you'd have to do on the pipeline:  mostly making sure that it is setup to select the tests using "Test run".  Make sure you don't have the phase setup to use multiple agents.

This Microsoft documentation covers it I think:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops